# Error FileNotFound System.Data.SqlClient when creating new database using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have begun learning about MVC and ASP.NET Core. I have been following an online video tutorial to get used to MVC and I have run into a problem when using the Entity Framework to create a database in localDb.

A database named 'AspNetBlog' should be created in the localDb (if it's not already created). This should happen in the BlogDataContext.cs model when overriding the OnConfiguring() method, as can be seen in BlogDataContext.cs.

The error that I am getting is "*FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.*"

The full output of the error can be seen here: https://gyazo.com/d8019f4b09732eb059bd291a7881b16b

Note that I have ensured that the localDb is running by going into the Command Prompt for VS2015 and entering sqllocaldb start.

I am not sure with what I have to do to fix this error and successfully create the DB. The tutorial was released in early 2015 and it was still using ASP.NET 5 at the time, so since I am sure that I've followed the tutorial correctly, I assume that the problem lies there.

Below you can see my code.

**BlogDataContext.cs**

The error is encountered when the statement "Database.EnsureCreated();" is reached. The output from Debug states "*Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in EntityFramework.Relational.dll*".

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AspNetBlog.Models
{
public class BlogDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public BlogDataContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        var connectionString = @"Server=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb;Database=AspNetBlog";

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
}
}
```

**Post.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AspNetBlog.Models
{

public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
}
```

**PostsController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using AspNetBlog.Models;

// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace AspNetBlog.Controllers
{
    public class PostsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Post post)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(post);

            post.PostedDate = DateTime.Now;
            post.Author = User.Identity.Name;

            // Create new instance of blog data context
            BlogDataContext db = new BlogDataContext();
            db.Posts.Add(post); // - What should be added
            await db.SaveChangesAsync(); // - Save changes to DB (Execute)

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**project.json**

Here you can see that I am using *"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8"*. In the tutorial I'm following, the version *"7.0.0-beta4"* is used instead. I tried using the same version as the one used in the tutorial, however it seems that it is not compatible with .NET Core.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Thank you for reading. Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a release candidate of Entity Framework Core. Try to update your project.json to point to it.

Comment: Tried replacing the "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8" with "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1" and it works as well. Thanks, I will continue using this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself finally. In the 'project.json' file I added the following dependency:

`"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0"`

Make sure that it's written that way, and not with lower-case letters. This was actually one of the first things I've tried but I wrote it in lower-case letters at first and got an error from the console. The tutorial I am doing is "Up and Running with ASP.NET 5". (So others like me who are doing this tutorial and ran into the same problem can find this, just in case)